# How to pass String argument?

Tags: android

I am having problem while passing string argument using javascript injection in my android application.. 
I am using the

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        " document.getElementById()
```

, but m not getting the exact output..

I want to connect my login form (locally created) with website, so that whenever user enter userID & password in my login form, it automatically get added to that website login form..

please help me with some simplified sample code.

Comment: Please include at least the full source code line that isn't working right, and preferably a little context.

Comment: EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
   webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        " document.getElementById('username').value = ' '; " + passwordEditText.getText().toString()
                        //"})()"
                        );     }  });
webview.loadUrl("https://login.yahoo.com/");

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not Enabled as Default for the `webview` . you have to enable it like below

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: yes, i already enabled javascript.. still m stuck.. i want to bind the txtpassword field (which i have created) with yahoo login form passwprd field, so that enter to that field atonce get enter to yahoo page..

Comment: @PPb: then check my post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866212/webview-problem-on-youtube-site-in-android